# Prove that if $x^x=4$ then $x=2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Trying to prove that I looked at $x\ln x=2\ln 2$ and stated that therefore $x=2$... It was just a little assumption in a big question. Now I see that $x^x$ is a composition of injections and therefore is an injection, and since $2^2=4$ then no other $x$ satisfies it. Am I relatively correct? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: draw the graph and use it to justify uniqueness of the solution

Comment: It is not a composition of injections, and it is not an injection.

Answer (score 12):

The function $x^x$ is undefined for $x\le 0$.

It is easy to show that $x^x\le 1$ for $0<x\le 1$.

The derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x(\ln x+1)$ which is positive for $x>1$.

Combined, these facts say that if $x^x=4$ then $x>1$. The function is increasing in that interval, so there can be at most one solution there. Therefore, there is at most one solution anywhere, and $x=2$ is it.

---

[Here is a method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2), using the Lambert W function, that can easily be extended to solve the equation $x^x=a$ uniquely for any $a\ge 1$.

$$x^x=4$$
$$x\ln x=\ln 4$$
$$e^{\ln x}\ln x=\ln 4$$
$$\ln x=\operatorname{W}(\ln 4)$$
$$x=e^{\operatorname{W}(\ln 4)}$$

The Lambert W function $\operatorname{W}(x)$ [is single-valued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) for $x>0$, and certainly $\ln 4>0$. So $x$ is well defined and [can be calculated by a variety of software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Software). We end up with the value $x=2$ in our particular case. This method shows that the value of $x$ has at most one solution in $x^x=a$ for $a\ge 1$.

(That list of software leaves out the [dmath package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dmath/) for Borland/Embarcadero Delphi, as well as the [Graph application](http://www.padowan.dk/).)

Comment: The function is defined for some negative x (in fact, for a dense subset of the negative reals).

Comment: @Paul: Sort of. When doing analysis work I have seen people limit the function to just positive reals, since it is so screwy on the negative reals. I simplified to get to the point. To get a controversy, just ask if it is defined at zero.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $z^w = e^{w \ln z}$. Set $e^{w \ln z} = 4$ with the condition that $w = z$ and solve it.

$e^{x \ln x} = 4 \Rightarrow x = \frac{\ln 4}{\ln 2} \Rightarrow x = 2$.

Comment: Can you justify that first implication? It certainly is not obvious and is equivalent to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\gt y \gt 1$ then $y^y\lt x^y\lt x^x$ so for $x\gt 1$ the function $x^x$ is increasing, and there is at most one solution in this range - the existence of a solution is not in doubt.

If $0\lt x\lt 1$ we have $x^x\lt 1$ and $1^1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can show that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\log_4(x)}$$
has an only fixed point.